# How to query stored PostGIS Raster data from within the IPython Notebook

Tags: postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy

Test data

- [1 TIF file](http://pastelink.me/dl/de3b6a) (159KB)

Goal threefold:

1. Load raster into PostGIS using `raster2pgsql` and visualize in QGIS
2. In my IPython Notebook connect to PostGIS and load raster into NumPy array
3. In my IPyhton Notebook use Pandas to load a time-series of one pixel of rasters with different time step stored in PostGIS

Process so far
I've managed to get one raster image into PostGIS Raster using the `raster2pgsql` command and visualize it in QGIS using the DB Manager:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -d -I -C -M -R -l 4 D:\Downloads\raster//modis.tif -F -t 100x100 public.ndvi | psql -U postgres -d rastertest -h localhost -p 5432
```

But how to access/query this raster from within IPython Notebook?

I found this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/camptocamp/geoalchemy), which is going about SQLALchemy and GeoAlchemy2. And where it is mentioned that it support PostGIS Raster as well. It seems to be very interesting! But using the [documentation](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core_tutorial.html) I don't see how I can apply this to Raster data

I think I can make a connection to my PostGIS database using the following code, where `postgres=user`, `password=admin` and `database=rastertest`:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost/rastertest', echo=True)
```

But then.. 
any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PostGIS, but if in the end it's just plain old SQL, you might wanna try `ipython-sql` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython-sql), which allows you to connect to a database and write queries in IPython notebook with %sql and %%sql magic, avoiding the ORM route entirely.

Comment: You want to visualize the raster in your ipython notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **psycopg** module to connect to a postgres db from python. Some code samples:

```
import psycopg2


def connect_db():

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='rastertest' user='admin' host='localhost' password='password'")
    conn.set_session(autocommit=True) #if you want your updates to take effect without being in a transaction and requiring a commit, for a beginner, I would set this to True
    return conn
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    return None

def get_raster(raster_id,conn):

    query= "SELECT ST_AsText(geom) from raster_table where id={}".format(raster_id)
    conn.cursor().execute(query)
    res = cur.fetchall()

    return res[0][0]
```

Maybe the text representation of the raster is something you can use.
Alternatively, take a look here http://postgis.net/docs/RT_reference.html to see if any of the functions return what you want for your numpy array and replace the query in get_raster accordingly. (Possibly this http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_DumpValues.html)

Comment: your post seems very interesting. Definitely will give it a try!